# Why is my android backstack size still 0 after FragmentTransaction.add()

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

Ok I am confused to hell right now.
I am running an Activity that extends FragmentActivity that implement Google maps v2.
So the map fragment is in the activty and is always running.

I now want to add a new fragment on top which I tried with getSupportFragmentManager() as well as getFragmentManager() and in both cases fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() is 0 after transaction.commit().

What this causes is when I open the new fragment on top of the map I cannot go back to map but just exit the app.

I know the both managers have different backstacks but neither of them actually showed any backstack ater commit.

Can someone explane please how should I approach this problem. Android complexities run deep :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue.Finally have to changed extends FragmentActivity to Activity.

Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getSupportFragmentManager, which returns the correct number:

```
@Override public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

You have to call a fm.executePendingTransactions() after ft.commit() or before fm.getBackStackEntryCount(). Because the commit() only schedules the transactions for a later pass.